# Scala - reflectively invoke private static method from Java

Tags: java, scala, reflection

I'm trying to take a `private static` method from a Java class and invoke it in Scala. Here's the code I have so far:

```
val blockClass = classOf[Block]
val aMethod: Method = blockClass.getDeclaredMethod("a", Integer.TYPE, classOf[String], classOf[Block])
aMethod.setAccessible(true)

aMethod.invoke(null, 145, "anvil", anvilPatch)
```

When I try to compile this, however, I get this error:

```
Error: the result type of an implicit conversion must be more specific than AnyRef
aMethod.invoke(null, 145, "anvil", null)
                     ^
```

That `145` is supposed to be a Java `int`, and `Integer.TYPE` is the only thing I could think of to get a Java `int`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the error happens, but it can be fixed simply by casting `145` to `AnyRef` (which is the same as `Object`) explicitly:

```
aMethod.invoke(null, 145.asInstanceOf[AnyRef], "anvil", anvilPatch)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Integer.TYPE`, try using `classOf[Int]`. This will get you the class object of Scala's `Int` type.

```
val aMethod: Method = blockClass.getDeclaredMethod("a", classOf[Int], classOf[String], classOf[Block])
```